# nonuniqueobjectexception when Updating Database and Database creating new records instead of updating existing ones

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sql-update

I'm having an issue which I don't really understand, especially since I just started working with databases. I keep getting an nonuniqueobjectexception, when I try to save two instances of the project into the database. When I save the session for Project it will keep all the information and update the database accordingly but the Inspection table which is connected to the Project database will continue to add new entries. I tried multiple fixes of trying to throw exceptions but I can't figure out a way to save the information in the table without creating new entries in the instance table. Can anyone give me any advice on how to tackle this issue and where to look?

```
public static void editProject(Long warehouseID, Long managerID, Long supervisorID,
                               Long classID, Long projectItemID, Long statusID,
                               Long stageID, Long typeID, String scope, Map<String, String>params, Long inspectionTN)        
                        throws ClassNotFoundException, ParseException    
{
    //Initialize Services
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    //Get essential project data
    Warehouse warehouse = (Warehouse) ProjectObjectService.get(warehouseID, "Warehouse");
    Person manager = (Person) ProjectObjectService.get(new Long(managerID), "Person");
    Person supervisor = (Person) ProjectObjectService.get(new Long(supervisorID), "Person");
    ProjectClass projectClass = (ProjectClass) ProjectObjectService.get(new Long(classID), "ProjectClass");
    ProjectStatus status = (ProjectStatus) ProjectObjectService.get(new Long(statusID), "ProjectStatus");
    ProjectItem item = (ProjectItem) ProjectObjectService.get(new Long(projectItemID), "ProjectItem");
    ProjectStage stage = (ProjectStage) ProjectObjectService.get(stageID, "ProjectStage");
    ProjectType pType = (ProjectType) ProjectObjectService.get(typeID, "ProjectType");

    String mcsNumString = params.get("mcsNumber");

    //ID's 
    String iIDString = params.get("inspectionID");
    String closeoutIDString = params.get("closeoutID");

    int mcsNum = -1;
    Long iID = (long)-1;
    Long closeoutID = (long)-1;

    //Parse mcsNumber, change to -1 if it's not a number
    try
    {
        mcsNum = Integer.parseInt(mcsNumString);
        iID = Long.parseLong(iIDString);
        closeoutID = Long.parseLong(closeoutIDString);
    }catch(Exception e){}

    //Inspections inspections=(Inspections) ProjectObjectService.get(iID, "Inspections");

    int shouldInvoice = Integer.parseInt(params.get("shouldInvoice"));
    int actualInvoice = Integer.parseInt(params.get("actualInvoice"));
    String notes = params.get("notes");

    //Additional fields
    String zachNotes = params.get("zachUpdates");
    String cost = params.get("cost");
    String customerNumber = params.get("customerNumber");
    //Parse change orders from strong
    String changeOrderJsonString = params.get("coItems");
    ChangeOrderService orderService = new ChangeOrderService();
    HashSet<ChangeOrder> changeOrders = ChangeOrderService.getChangeOrdersFromString(changeOrderJsonString);

    Date fsalvageDate = null;
    Date finitiatedDate = null;
    Date fsurvey = null;
    Date fcostco = null;
    Date fproposal = null;
    Date fasBuilts = null;
    Date fpunchList = null;
    Date falarmHvac = null;
    Date fverisae = null;
    Date fcloseoutBook = null;
    Date fcloseoutNotes = null;
    Date fstart = null;
    Date fscheduled = null;
    Date factual = null;
    Date fairGas = null;
    Date fpermits = null;
    Date permitApp = null;

    Date fframing = null ; 
    Date fceiling = null; 
    Date froughMech = null; 
    Date froughElec= null;  
    Date froughPlumb = null; 
    Date fmechLightSmoke = null; 
    Date fmechFinal = null; 
    Date  felecFinal = null; 
    Date fplumbFinal = null; 
    Date ffireMarshal = null; 
    Date fhealth = null; 
    Date fbuildFinal = null; 

    //assign values to dates, if they are not null
    if (!(params.get("salvageDate")).isEmpty())
        fsalvageDate = formatter.parse(params.get("salvageDate"));

    if (!(params.get("initiated")).isEmpty())
        finitiatedDate = formatter.parse(params.get("initiated"));

    if (!(params.get("survey")).isEmpty())
        fsurvey = formatter.parse(params.get("survey"));

    if (!(params.get("costco")).isEmpty())
        fcostco = formatter.parse(params.get("costco"));

    if (!(params.get("proposal")).isEmpty())
        fproposal = formatter.parse(params.get("proposal"));

    if (!(params.get("asBuilts")).isEmpty())
        fasBuilts = formatter.parse(params.get("asBuilts"));

    if (!(params.get("punchList")).isEmpty())
        fpunchList = formatter.parse(params.get("punchList"));

    if (!(params.get("alarmHvac")).isEmpty())
        falarmHvac = formatter.parse(params.get("alarmHvac"));

    if (!params.get("verisae").isEmpty())
        fverisae = formatter.parse(params.get("verisae"));

    if (!params.get("startDate").isEmpty())
        fstart = formatter.parse(params.get("startDate"));

    if (!params.get("scheduledTurnover").isEmpty())
        fscheduled = formatter.parse(params.get("scheduledTurnover"));

    if (!params.get("actualTurnover").isEmpty())
        factual = formatter.parse(params.get("actualTurnover"));

    if (!params.get("airGas").isEmpty())
        fairGas = formatter.parse(params.get("airGas"));

    if (!params.get("permits").isEmpty())
        fpermits = formatter.parse(params.get("permits"));

    if (!params.get("permitApp").isEmpty())
        permitApp = formatter.parse(params.get("permitApp"));

    if(!params.get("framing").isEmpty()) 
        fframing = formatter.parse(params.get("framing"));

    if(!params.get("ceiling").isEmpty()) 
        fceiling = formatter.parse(params.get("ceiling"));

    if(!params.get("roughMech").isEmpty()) 
        froughMech = formatter.parse(params.get("roughMech"));

    if(!params.get("roughElec").isEmpty()) 
        froughElec = formatter.parse(params.get("roughElec"));

    if(!params.get("roughPlumb").isEmpty()) 
        froughPlumb = formatter.parse(params.get("roughPlumb"));

    if(!params.get("mechLightSmoke").isEmpty()) 
        fmechLightSmoke = formatter.parse(params.get("mechLightSmoke"));

    if(!params.get("mechFinal").isEmpty()) 
        fmechFinal = formatter.parse(params.get("mechFinal"));

    if(!params.get("elecFinal").isEmpty()) 
        felecFinal = formatter.parse(params.get("elecFinal"));

    if(!params.get("plumbFinal").isEmpty()) 
        fplumbFinal = formatter.parse(params.get("plumbFinal"));

    if(!params.get("fireMarshal").isEmpty()) 
        ffireMarshal = formatter.parse(params.get("fireMarshal"));

    if(!params.get("health").isEmpty()) 
        fhealth = formatter.parse(params.get("health"));

    if(!params.get("buildFinal").isEmpty()) 
        fbuildFinal = formatter.parse(params.get("buildFinal"));

    CloseoutDetails cd = null;

    if(cd==null)
    {
         cd = new CloseoutDetails();
         System.out.println("CloseoutDetails was empty in edit");
    }

    //Closeout fields
    cd.setPunchList(fpunchList);
    cd.setAsBuilts(fasBuilts);
    cd.setAirGas(fairGas);
    cd.setAlarmHvacForm(falarmHvac);
    cd.setCloseoutBook(fcloseoutBook);
    cd.setCloseoutNotes(fcloseoutNotes);
    cd.setPermitsClosed(fpermits);
    cd.setPunchList(fpunchList);
    cd.setVerisaeShutdownReport(fverisae);
    //need to add salvage amount and date

    Inspections inspections = null;
    //create inspections Object.
    if(inspections==null)
    {
         inspections = new Inspections();
         System.out.println("Inpsections was empty in edit");
    }       
    //set inspection fields
    inspections.setTicketNumber(inspectionTN);
    inspections.setFraming(fframing);
    inspections.setCeiling(fceiling);
    inspections.setRoughin_Mechanical(froughMech);
    inspections.setRoughin_Electric(froughElec);
    inspections.setRoughin_Plumbing(froughPlumb);
    inspections.setMechanicalLightSmoke(fmechLightSmoke);
    inspections.setMechanical_Final(fmechFinal);
    inspections.setElectrical_Final(felecFinal);
    inspections.setPlumbing_Final(fplumbFinal);
    inspections.setFire_Marshal(ffireMarshal);
    inspections.setHealth(fhealth);
    inspections.setBuilding_Final(fbuildFinal);

    /*try{
    inspections.setId(iID);
    ProjectObjectService.editObject("Inspections",iID,inspections);
    }catch (NonUniqueObjectException nuoe){}*/

    //Create new project to replace the old one
    Project p = new Project();
    p.setMcsNumber(mcsNum);
    p.setProjectClass(projectClass);
    p.addProjectManager(manager);
    p.addSupervisor(supervisor);
    p.setStatus(status);
    p.setWarehouse(warehouse);
    p.setScope(scope);
    p.setProjectItem(item);
    p.setStage(stage);
    p.setProjectInitiatedDate(finitiatedDate);
    p.setSiteSurvey(fsurvey);
    p.setCostcoDueDate(fcostco);
    p.setProposalSubmitted(fproposal);
    p.setScheduledStartDate(fstart);
    p.setScheduledTurnover(fscheduled);
    p.setActualTurnover(factual);
    p.setShouldInvoice(shouldInvoice);
    p.setInvoiced(actualInvoice);
    p.setProjectNotes(notes);
    p.setChangeOrders(changeOrders);
    p.setProjectType(pType);
    p.setZachUpdates(zachNotes);
    p.setCost(cost);
    p.setCustomerNumber(customerNumber);
    p.setPermitApplication(permitApp);

    p.setCloseoutDetails(cd);
    p.setInspections(inspections);

    //Replace the old project with the new project.
    Long id = Long.parseLong(params.get("projectID"));

    //ProjectObjectService.editObject("Project", id,p);
    long[] iDs = {iID,/*closeoutID,*/id} ;
    String[] domains = {"Inspections",/*"CloseoutDetails",*/"Project" };
    ProjectObject[] objects ={inspections, /*cd,*/ p};

    inspections.setId(iID);
    ProjectObjectService.editObject("Project",id,p);
}

public static Object get(Long id, String domain) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    //Get the Class from parsing the "domain" string.
    Class c = Class.forName("projectObjects."+domain);

    //Get object from database that matches the id
    Object o = session.get(c, id);
    tx.commit();
    return o;
}
```